# A Trigonometry Question ??

Tags: trigonometry

If $3\cos x = 5\sin x$ , then the value of

$$\frac{5\sin x - 2\sec^3x  + 2 \cos x}{5\sin x + 2\sec^3 x  - 2\cos x}$$

I have solved till    $\frac{5\cos^4x-2}{\cos^4x +2}$. BUT I AM NOT ABLE TO GET ANY FURTHER..WHAT TO DO.?

Comment: Use the fact that $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x = 1$, along with the given relation $3 \cos x = 5 \sin x$, to find the value of $\cos^2 x$ (which then gives the value of $\cos^4 x$).

Comment: Try not to use all caps.  It's not polite.

Comment: I'll remember that the next time thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$9\cos^2 x = 25\sin^2 x$$
$$\cos^2 x + \frac{9}{25}\cos^2 x = 1$$
$$\cos^2 x = \frac{25}{34}$$
$$\cos^4 x = \frac{625}{1156}$$

Substitute this in the expression that you arrived at to get the final value.

Comment: DO you know of any short-cut OR quicker METHOD to ARRIVE AT THE ANSWER QUICKLY because in MCQ exams we dont need the steps just the answer....AND THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER IT WORKED FOR ME...!

Comment: Can you give me the options provided for the question ? You need to calculate till the step I mentioned above. And after that instead of calculating the result you can go with the last digit calculation. This might help you depending on the options given to the question.

Comment: Ok the options were A) 271/979  B) 316/2937  C) 542/2937  D) None of these

Comment: @Sudhanshu Please do not write all in capitals, it looks very impolite and untidy.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is correct. Apply what lsp wrote and replace. So, the numerator of your last expression is
5 (625 / 1156) - 2 = 813 / 1156
and the denominator is
625 / 1156 + 2 = 2937 / 1156
Then the ratio of  numerator to denominator is 813 / 2937 = 271 / 979

Answer (score 0):

If $tan(x) = 3/5, then sin(x) = 3/\sqrt { 34 }, cos(x) = 5/\sqrt{34} $ so reduce your entire equation to either cos(x) or sin(x) and you will end up with $\frac { 5\quad Cos^{ 4 }\left( x \right) -2 }{ Cos^{ 4 }\left( x \right) +2 } $.

Substitute cos(x) and you will end up with 813/2937.